# AWK invalid char ''' in expression

Tags: awk

The AWK command doesn't execute in a script but when checking in online awk validator shows my script has invalid char ''' in expression. Surprisingly I haven't changed anything in the awk command and was running all good till yesterday.

```
My Script:



awk '
BEGIN{ FS="," }
{           
    machinename=$1
    compornot=$3
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($1 == machinename) {
                    if (compornot == "compliant" && $3 == "compliant") {
                            value = "NA"
                    } else if (compornot == "noncompliant" && $3 == "noncompliant") {
                            value = "No"
                    } else {
                            value = "Yes"
                    }
           } 
   }

    print $1 "," $2 "," compornot "," value "," $3
}
' $SCRIPT_PATH/$SCRIPT_NAME/kraft_ansible_temp.csv | tee $SCRIPT_PATH/$SCRIPT_NAME/kraft_ansible_temp.csv


Error in online AWK validator:



gawk: prog.awk:1: awk '
gawk: prog.awk:1:     ^ invalid char ''' in expression
gawk: prog.awk:1: awk '
gawk: prog.awk:1:     ^ syntax error`
```

Comment: Thanks but when running in a shell script the command is not getting executed neither it is throwing any error. Printing lines inside the block is also not working. That's why I suspected something wrong with the syntax because of which it is not executing the command

Comment: Your shell command is enclosed in a pair of backticks (the first backtick was deleted by you with an edit apparently), meaning that the output of the command is captured. Remove the backticks and you will see the output of awk.

Comment: Sorry that backtick is not in my command but got inserted while creating this question. Updated it

Comment: I ran it and it seems to work just fine. Maybe you left something out. Some design flaws: `machinename=$1` - - `if ($1 == machinename)` and `compornot=$3` - - `if (compornot == "compliant" && $3 == "compliant")` seem pretty redundant.

Comment: Please provide the URL for the "online awk validator" you're using (I'm just curious, @blhsing has already answered your question correctly).

Answer (score 1):

The "script" you posted is a shell script, not an awk script. It does not conform to awk's syntax but rather a shell's, hence the syntax error.

The code between the two single quotes, on the other hand, is properly awk, so you should have the awk syntax validator validate that instead.